# Force dispose Control

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a panel representing some complex object, basically this is just a `ListBox` with horizontal `StackPanel`'s. Those panels have some inner click handlers, bindings etc. There is also a "Refresh" button that removes all those panels and creates new ones. Now when there are about 50 inner `StackPanel`'s and this button is clicked about 20 times my application becomes very slow and unresponsive and each next click only makes things worse. I was able to find out that all those inner panels are still in memory. I tried detaching all the possible handlers and removing bindings. But whatever I do there are still memory leaks. So the question is: is there actually a way to explicitly free the memory consumed by `System.Windows.Controls.Control` or any pattern that can guarantee correct memory handling? By the way i have just the same project for WPF and nothing is wrong there, leaks only happen in Silverlight

Comment: We'd need to see some code...try to come up with as small of an application as you can that replicates the problem.  Somewhere you're holding onto a reference to the objects, and there's no way for us to tell you where with with what you've posted here.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post any code, but even if I could the project is too big and trimming it to readable size would have taken too much time. I was hoping that there is some trick with GC or weak references or at least unsafe code to mark those controls as garbage

Comment: Nope, not really.  If the GC isn't able to clean them up then something somewhere is referencing them.  If you could force the deletion of them then that code would break when it when to access the reference.  Not getting errors like that (accessing unallocated memory) is the reason to use a language like C# with managed memory.  It prevents you from being in the position where that can happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly manage memory, but you can be careful about references and cleaning things up.

A couple of tips:  You can try using the weak reference class which is available in Silverlight: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.95).aspx

Secondly, the issue is most likely that you have not cleaned up the Event Handlers.  You need to specifically unreferenced them when you are done with each one.  Failing to do so will make it so the GC cannot collect them.

Third: Try Caliburn.Micro to help you bind without using events which I am told can cause memory leaks.  He has some clever workarounds for these memory leak issues so you don't have to use events at all.

Greg

Comment: Thanks for directions, my issue was caused by self-written auto-close Popup not freeing some resources. This is why the problem wasn't occuring in WPF - there is out-of-box support for this behavior in it

Comment: Great, glad you got this resolved.